# How to get max Y value from StackedBarChart (jFreeChart)?

Tags: java, jfreechart

How to get the maximum axis value from a created chart?

Here is how it is created:

```
final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createStackedBarChart("", "", symbol, dataSet,PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, false, false);
```

I probably have to get the dataset from the chart and then get the maximum axis value from it. The dataset is `DefaultCategoryDataset`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just iterate through the `CategoryDataset`

```
CategoryDataset dataset = createDataset();
for (int r = 0; r < dataset.getRowCount(); r++) {
    double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int c = 0; c < dataset.getColumnCount(); c++) {
        Number number = dataset.getValue(r, c);
        double value = number == null ? Double.NaN : number.doubleValue();
        if (value > max) {
            max = value;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(dataset.getRowKey(r) + ": " + max);
}
```

Using the [example dataset](https://sourceforge.net/p/jfreechart/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/source/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.java#l83), produces the following output:

```
First: 5.0
Second: 8.0
Third: 6.0
```

Comment: Thanks! I want just to add (for the others like me): the dataset allows null values so check if `dataset.getValue(r, c)` is not null before getting its double or whatever value.

Comment: @Maistora: Well spotted! I've updated the example; `Double.NaN` is [_unordered_](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3) and always compares `false`.

Comment: What if I'm using `TimeTableXYDataset`, not `CategoryDataset`?

Comment: I think you can just loop over `getSeriesCount()` and `getItemCount()`, checking `getY(s, i)` as you go; ping me if you pose a question on this.